# Extraction of data from a delimited string in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a string variable which has some data as shown below:

```
'From\tTo\nA0A3Q8IUE6\t13392634\nA4I9M8\t5072523\nE9BQL4\t13392634\nQ4Q3E9\t5654813\nE9B4M7\t13452251\nA0A088S7I8\t22574266\nA4HAG8\t5414882\nA0A3P3Z499\t5414882'
```

The data basically has two columns 'From' and 'To'. How do I extract the entries from the 'To' column in python?

Comment: Do some research on regex and the `split` function.

Comment: Use awk -F'\t'  Something like: `awk -F'\t' '{print $2}' <(echo -e 'From\tTo\nA0A3Q8IUE6\t13392634\nA4I9M8\t5072523\nE9BQL4\t13392634\nQ4Q3E9\t5654813\nE9B4M7\t13452251\nA0A088S7I8\t22574266\nA4HAG8\t5414882\nA0A3P3Z499\t5414882'})`

Comment: In Python (if the string is `yourstring`): `[value.split('\t')[1] for value in yourstring.split('\n')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split, and then extract the data from the odd indexes, like so:

```py
data = 'From\tTo\nA0A3Q8IUE6\t13392634\nA4I9M8\t5072523\nE9BQL4\t13392634\nQ4Q3E9\t5654813\nE9B4M7\t13452251\nA0A088S7I8\t22574266\nA4HAG8\t5414882\nA0A3P3Z499\t5414882'

print(data)
data = data.split()
to = [data[i] for i in range(3, len(data), 2)]
print(to)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python you could split a string at specific chars, in your case `\n` delimits the `row` and `\t` delimits the `column`

something like this should work:

```
string='From\tTo\nA0A3Q8IUE6\t13392634\nA4I9M8\t5072523\nE9BQL4\t13392634\nQ4Q3E9\t5654813\nE9B4M7\t13452251\nA0A088S7I8\t22574266\nA4HAG8\t5414882\nA0A3P3Z499\t5414882'
f=[]
t=[]
for row in string.split("\n")[1:]:
    fr,to=row.split("\t")
    f.append(fr)
    t.append(to)

print(f,t)
```